# How to pass CommandText to another MySqlCommand?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

The title is a bit furviant, I'll try to explain better. So in my application I've two connection string, one for the local database, and another for the web database. This two database must be updated with the same records. Now in my app when I add a record in the local database I execute a function that pass the `MySqlCommand` object to another function that use another connection string for the web database. In this second function I need to execute the same operation already performed in the local database. Example code:

**Function local database**

```
 Dim query = "INSERT INTO text_app (name, last_name)
                                        VALUES(@namep, @last_namep)"

 Dim MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)

 MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@namep", name.Text)
 MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_namep", last_name.Text)

 MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

 Sync.SyncOut(MySqlCommand) 'Pass the object to another function
```

**Function web database (SyncOut)**

```
Using dbCon As MySqlConnection = establishWebConnection()

        Try
            dbCon.Open()
            Dim MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query_command, dbCon)

            MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 

            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Using
```

Now `query_command` contain the `MySqlCommand` passed from the local function, `dbCon` is the new connection object.

When I perform the `.ExecuteNonQuery` on the `SyncOut` function I get this error:

> Invalid Cast from 'MySqlCommand' type to 'String' type.

What I need is take the `.CommandText` property contained in the `query_command`, but I can't access to this property. 
What exactly am I doing wrong? How I can achieve this?

Comment: Why you can't access that property? It is public read/write so it should be available

Comment: the variable "query_command" contains only: .Equal .GetHashCode .GetType .ToString. NB: I can read the property .CommandText in the function local but not in the web function SyncOut. Maybe I should convert it?

Comment: How you declare the function SyncOut?

Comment: The function is declared in another class called "Sync", if you see in my post: Sync.SyncOut

Comment: I mean, how do you declare the parameter query_command passed to the function. IE _Public Sub SyncOut(ByVal query_command as ???? )_

Comment: You have right Steve I add as MySqlCommand and now the previous error is fixed but I still can't execute the query on the other db. I get "Failed error encountered during command execution". The web db have the same column name.

Comment: Usually this is accompained by an InnerException message that explains better the situation. Look at your MainException.InnerException.Message

Comment: Uhm, I can't see anywhere a call to _dbCon.Open()_ in SyncOut

Comment: Ok the InnerException say: parameter @namep must be defined. But the parameters are defined in the local function not in the web function, maybe I should redeclare all the parameter? But at this point, passing the query_command is usefullness.. PS: No the connection is open, I missing to insert this is in example, now I update.

Comment: Yes, you need to redeclare them in the new command, no, it is not useless because otherwise you need to pass all the parameters and the command text

Comment: Okay but query_command is the previous MySqlCommand used in the local function, so the paremeter isn't already included as the query?

Comment: No, you are creating and executing a different command that happens to have the same commandtext not the other properties (Parameters collection included)

Comment: And if I do MySqlCommand.Parameters = query_command.Parameters? Should be working. I just tried I get the property is read only error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is change the name of the variable that represent the MySqlCommand. I can't find any plausible reason to allow a confusion as this to spread along your code. Do not name a variable with the same name of its class even if the language permits, it is very confusing

```
Dim query = "INSERT INTO text_app (name, last_name)
                        VALUES(@namep, @last_namep)"

Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)
```

and, of course, change every reference to the old name with the new one.

Now in the declaration of SyncOut write

```
Public Sub SyncOunt(ByVal cmd As MySqlCommand)
   ...
   ' Do not forget to open the connection '
   dbCon.Open()
   Dim aDifferentCommand = cmd.Clone()
   aDifferentCommand.Connection = dbCon  
   ....
```

Comment: I need to pass the parameter in your "cmd" 'cause the SyncOut function doesn't know what are the parameters. This function is used by different class that perform a only operation: sync the data in the db online.

Comment: I have no MySql installed at hand here, but you could try to use the Clone method then

Comment: Updated the answer, yes, tested on SqlCommand for Sql Server  and it duplicates everything (it makes a deep copy) If MySql version works alike ... do not forget to change the connection of course

Comment: Okay but when I do ExecuteNonQuery I get: System.NullReferenceException

Comment: I am unable to see if there is something null here. I have tried in LinqPAD without opening a real connection but everything seems fine here. I can only suggest to start a debug session and check what variable is null (nothing in vb)

Comment: It's too strange, there's a particular Exception that I can use like InnerException to understand which parameter is null? The strange thing is that the local function execute correctly the query but the web function "SyncOut" return this exception :\